# WAMP failed to open stream for root backslash

Tags: apache, wampserver, filepath

I had to rebuild my machine and reinstall the WAMP server. The server starts fine but I'm not able to view my website via localhost. I keep getting warning errors: Warning: include(/variables.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory ...

I know the error is because I use the root backslash when calling files i.e.

```
<?php include "/variables.php"; ?>
```

If I change it to

```
<?php include "variables.php"; ?>
```

without the root backslash the localhost works fine. I'd like to keep my files with the root backslash (that's how it's saved on the server that's actually hosting my site). Is there a configuration or a module in apache or something that' I'm missing that would allow WAMP to allow me to keep the root backslash?

Comment: You need to call the proper path to `variables.php` if calling from root eg. `<?php include "/variables/variables.php"; ?>`

Comment: Not a good idea. Remember that where your code is in relation to the root is not likely to be the same path on ANY 2 servers. Use a relative path